# Socket.io: módulo não pode ser encontrado

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Estava aqui "brincando" com Socket.io, tudo funcionando legal, quando dei o comando `node app.js` de uma hora para outra o NodeJS me retorna um erro (ele estava funcionando antes)

> Cannot find module 'socket.io'

Busquei outro exemplo na internet colei e ele sempre me diz a mesma coisa. Mas quando entro no node pelo cmd e executo `var foo = require('socket.io');` ele encontra o módulo sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Já instalaste o módulo? Fizeste `npm install socket.io --save`?

Comment: Sim, instalei. Estou agora tentando instalar o módulo no dir da aplicação

Comment: Não @Sergio, mas instalei agora o módulo no dir do app

Comment: E agora ele já encontra?

Comment: Funcionou, mas estou meio "esperto" talvez volte a parar de funcionar

Comment: Se usaste `--save` ele fica gravado no `package.json` e vai ser instalado quando fizeres `npm install` da aplicação na próxima vez. Parece que o Walker respondeu com a resposta, se o problema era esse podes aceitar a resposta dele.

Comment: Sim, estava apenas esperando um pouco aqui, mas aparentemente está tudo nos conformes. Resposta certa a dele. Mas vou abrir outra pergunta pois me deparei com outro erro no meu app.

Comment: É boa ideia esperar mais tempo antes de aceitar é verdade. Neste caso era simples, em casos mais complexos podem vir respostas mais elaboradas mais tarde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente instalar o pacote, no diretório do arquivo app.js, digite `npm install socket.io`

O NPM é um gerenciador de pacotes do NodeJS, para usá-lo é simples. Primeiro cria-se o manifesto da sua aplicação com o comando `npm init`, ele fará algumas perguntas e irá gerar o arquivo package.json onde ficará armazenado entre outras coisas, as dependências de sua aplicação.

As dependências instaladas com o comando `npm install` são salvas no diretório node_modules dentro do seu projeto. Se você adicionar a opção save (`npm install --save pacote`) a dependência é salva permanentemente no manifesto.

Para instalar todas as dependências de um pacote usando o manifesto, basta rodar o comando `npm install` no diretório de sua aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado e parabéns @WalkerLeite

Comment: @Gustavo podes também aproveitar para dar `+1` à resposta :)